# protractor different mock httpbackend responses

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, gulp-protractor

I'm using a mock module for some testing.

When a page gets loaded e.g.

```
    browser.get('http://localhost:5643/#/balance/import');
```

this api url below gets called and we get the below response which works just fine.

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://localhost:44329/api/daystatus').respond(
                {
                    'DayID': 249,
                    'weekend': false,
                    'dayStatusTypeID': 5,
                    'balance': null
                }
            );
```

But when another page gets loaded e.g.

```
    browser.get('http://localhost:5643/#/dashboard');
```

and also calls the api url in the mock module

but this time I want it to return different response. (Because the previous page was loaded and some UI test actions took place.)

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://localhost:44329/api/daystatus').respond(
                {
                    'DayID': 249,
                    'weekend': false,
                    'dayStatusTypeID': 7,
                    'balance': null
                }
            );
```

How can I say in my mock module to use the second call to the API url this time not the first? At the moment whatever page I load it uses:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://localhost:44329/api/daystatus').respond(
                {
                    'DayID': 249,
                    'weekend': false,
                    'dayStatusTypeID': 5,
                    'balance': null
                }
            );
```

Can I detect which page the request came from..or can I pass in querystring variables? Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distinguish the API calls by the `Referer` header:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://localhost:44329/api/daystatus', 
                     {'Referer': 'http://localhost:5643/#/balance/import'})
```

and:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://localhost:44329/api/daystatus', 
                     {'Referer': 'http://localhost:5643/#/dashboard'})
```